Error Cannot find native module ExpoFontLoader
I have created new react-native-tv-os project and added react-native-vector-icons and try to use below code at that time this issue occurs
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
const IconMoonIcons = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig, 'icomoon', 'icomoon.ttf');

Platform Where the issue is : Android

System:
      OS: macOS 14.3
      Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 20.12.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.22 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 10.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2024.05.06.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 23.4, iOS 17.4, macOS 14.4, tvOS 17.4, visionOS 1.1, watchOS 10.4
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
      Xcode: 15.3/15E204a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^50.0.14 => 50.0.18 
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-native-tvos:  0.74.0-0rc1 

